# Plotting distribution from sampled data in python

Tags: python, plot, machine-learning, distribution

I have two sets of sampled points in 2d space[x ,y], each set represents one class. When I plot all points, it's mess and one can't see anything on it. I need somehow plot distribution of each set (if it's possible on same canvas with different colours, then better). Does anybody know about some good library for it?

Comment: see seaborn https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/distributions.html

Comment: this is not what I ment exactly. Those histograms are nice, but I need histograms of two classes in that one picture. How can I do that?

Comment: Call the code once for each class with alpha (transparency)

Comment: can you give me simple example, please? I don't know what you mean. Does transparency print it with same mean and deviation?

Answer (score -1):

Matplotlib is a very good library for that task. You can plot histograms, scatter plots and lot of other things. You just have to know what you want and then you can probably do it with that. I use that for similar tasks a lot.

[UPDATE]
As I said, you can do that with matplotlib. Here is an example from their gallery: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_hist.html

It's not so pretty as with the answer in the comment of @lejlot, but still correct.

Comment: I know about histograms, but can I do something like this? 
http://cloud.originlab.com/www/products/images/Marginal_distribution_curve_c1.png

Comment: Nice plot :-) I am sure you can do that as well. An easier solution would be, to make subplots in a grid of 2x2. Top-left is a histogram for the x-axis, bottom left is the scatter plot, bottom right is the histogram for the y-axis. (for that you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333568/vertical-histogram-in-python-and-matplotlib )