# How to plot a histogram on the right of the plot as a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, data-visualization, histogram

I am trying to make a plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POwDH.png). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEPng.png) is my dataset with the subplots as histogram. But i am unable to make this like in the above figure.

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
(fig, [[ax1, ax2],[ax3, ax4]]) = plt.subplots(2,2,sharex=False, sharey = False)

ax1.plot(delta828[:-3],'oy', label='%.3f$\pm$%.3f'%(np.mean(delta828[:-3]),np.std(delta828[:-3])))
ax1.axhline(np.mean(delta828),color='y',ls='--')
ax1.axhspan(np.mean(delta828[:-3])-np.std(delta828[:-3]),np.mean(delta828[:-3])+np.std(delta828[:-3]),color='y',alpha=0.15,ec='none')
ax1.set_ylabel(u'$\delta^{12}$C$^{18}$O$_2$ / \u2030')
ax1.set_xlabel('Measurement cycle')
ax1.legend(loc = 'upper right')


ax3.plot(delta628[:-3],'or',label='%.3f$\pm$%.3f'%(np.mean(delta628[:-3]),np.std(delta628[:-3])))
ax3.axhline(np.mean(delta628[:-3]),color='r',ls='--')
ax3.axhspan(np.mean(delta628[:-3])-np.std(delta628[:-3]),np.mean(delta628[:-3])+np.std(delta628[:-3]),color='r',alpha=0.15,ec='none')
ax3.set_ylabel(u'$\delta^{12}$C$^{16}$O$^{18}$O / \u2030')
ax3.legend(loc = 'upper right')
ax3.set_xlabel('Measurement cycle')

(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(delta828[:-3])
bins = 20
n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(delta828[:-3], 20, density=True, facecolor='yellow')
# ax3.hist(delta828[:-3], bins = 20)
y = norm.pdf( bins, mu, sigma)
ax2.plot(bins,y, 'r--', linewidth=2)

(mu, sigma) = norm.fit(delta628[:-3])
bins = 20
n, bins, patches = ax4.hist(delta628[:-3], 20, density=True, facecolor='red')
# ax3.hist(delta828[:-3], bins = 20)
y = norm.pdf( bins, mu, sigma)
ax4.plot(bins,y, 'g--', linewidth=2)

plt.tight_layout()**
```

Comment: Did you try `ax2.hist(..., orientation="horizontal")`?  [Vertical histogram in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333568/vertical-histogram-in-python-and-matplotlib)

Comment: Will a standard [joint plot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html#plotting-joint-and-marginal-distributions) with marginal distributions from Seaborn be enough for what you're trying to achieve?